# Invert dictionary with set of values from the original dict's values

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I have been trying to invert a Python dictionary, i.e. taking from an original dict all values, get a unique set and use these as keys for a new dict. Values for the new keys should be a list of the original dict's keys, which had the new dict key as value.

Certainly there are better ways, but I came up with:

```
myDict1 = {'foo0':'alpha','foo1':'alpha','bar0':'beta','bar4':'beta'}
tmpDict = dict.fromkeys(set(myDict1.values()),[])
for thingy in myDict1.keys():
    tmpDict[myDict1[thingy]].append(thingy)
print(tmpDict)
```

giving `tmpDict` as:

```
{'alpha': ['bar0', 'foo0', 'foo1', 'bar4'], 'beta': ['bar0', 'foo0', 'foo1', 'bar4']}
```

which is not the expected dict:

```
{'alpha': ['foo0', 'foo1'], 'beta': ['bar0', 'bar4']}
```

Where is the error?

Comment: Why do you have `set(myDict1.keys())`? `for thingy in myDict1` would behave identically.

Comment: That one is probably just a remnant while trying to get it working and moving stuff around - I see no reason why I added it there right now. I have edited the question.

Thanks for pointing to the previous question! Good to know about the referencial behaviour of `fromkeys()` etc.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `fromkeys`, all the keys point to the same object. In this case a list:

```
dict.fromkeys(set(myDict1.values()),[])
```

I would suggest using:

```
dict((k, []) for k in set(myDict1.values()))
```

Which would create a new list for each key.